# This doesn't look like a function. What is this?

Tags: c, arrays

A friend asked me to write a function in C to return the 100th element of an array. I'm not very familiar with C, so I wasn't sure how to make a generic function that could do this with any type of array, so I cheated and assumed that it was an array of integers and wrote this function:

```
int GetHundredthElement(int *array) {
  return array[100 - 1];
}
```

(the `- 1` is there because arrays are zero-indexed)

I asked him how to make a function that would work for any type of array. He told me there was a simple way to do it:

```
int GetHundredthElement = 100 - 1;
```

and that this "function" could be called like this:

```
GetHundredthElement[array];
```

I tried it, and it worked, but doesn't look like a function to me because it uses bracket notation, which isn't how function calls are written in C. I don't really understand exactly what this code is doing or how it's doing it. What's going on here?

Comment: @K-ballo has the right answer. However, in the future, when you want to make more complex functions that take any arbitrary precision type (int, float, double, etc.), AND if you have access to C++ (which I realize the question specifically says C), look into `templates`. They're an amazing addition to C++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right about the fact that `GetHundredthElement` is not a function-- it is, as you would expect, an integer.

However, this illustrates a surprising ability in C where you can reverse the order of your array access!

```
assert(a[5] == 5[a]);
```

This is because an array access can be implemented in pointer arithmetic:

```
assert(a[5] == *(a+5));
assert(*(a+5) == *(5+a));
assert(*(5+a) == 5[a]);
```

Answer (score 11):

It's not a function, it simply takes advantage of a little-known C fact that array indexes can be interchanged. All the `x[y]` notation really means is that you're accessing the xth offset of the y array. But you could just as easily write `y[x]` in your case and get the same result.

`99[array]` and `array[99]` are interchangeable and mean the same thing. By declaring GetHundredthElement to be 99, your friend played a neat trick :)

You CAN however write a generic function to get the hundredth element of an array fairly easily using *C++* templates (not C).

Comment: Note that this is because x[y] is equivalent to *(x+y). Since addition is commutative, this is *(y+x) which is then y[x].

Answer (score 5):

When using pointers, `pointer[ index ]` and `index[ pointer ]` are actually the same. It's not a function, its a regular operator; its the same as `array[ GetHundredthElement ]` or `array[ 100 - 1 ]`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the special funky way you can access arrays.

Let's recall that arrays can be treated like pointers, and you can use arithmetic.

For example:

let `x` be some arbitrary array:

```
int x[4];
```

Implies accessing `x`'s 5th element, which is `*(x+4)`.

Terrible example of memory layout:

```
x -> [0][1][2][3][4]
```

Now, the weird thing you can do with C arrays/pointers to blocks, is flip the number and variable in bracket notation.

```
x[4] is equal to 4[x]
```

Because they break down to:

```
*(x+4) and *(4+x)
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, how would you represent `x[4][4]` backwards? Would it be `(4*4)[x]` ?

Comment: @Amit - I have to confess I don't know how to do it the weird little way with multi-dimensional arrays. `(4*4)[x]` would not compile because it's like saying `x[16]` (only one dimension so if you wanted one value specifically, that's not going to work). Since the array name only shows up once, you can only really do this trick like this `4[x][4]`. The arithmetic way to do it, however, is `*(*(x+4)+4);`. Yes I know that also looks funky.

Comment: @Amit: I guess it would be `4[x[4]]` or `4[4[x]]`. I can't test this moment, though, so that may be just rubbish.

Answer (score 2):

In C, the bracket notation is short hand for pointer arithmetic. A normal use like `x[i]` is syntactically equivalent to `*(x + i)` (remember that arrays are pointers). If instead you had used `i[x]` then it's the same as `*(i + x)` and produces the same output. As noted by other answers, this approach is not a function, just an interesting technique.